# JAXB Ignore 'extra' elements from Response XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I am getting a XML response and it keeps on changing very frequently (nodes keep on increasing or reducing). After each updation in response xml my code breaks as my mapped Java class does not have all fileds.

Is there any way to avoid my code breaking if any changes occurs in response XML.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To cope with unknown fields, you can add a `List<Object>` property annotated `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)`

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
private List<Object> anything;
```

Any elements in the input that do not correspond to explicit properties of the class will be swept up into this list.  If the element is known to the `JAXBContext` you'll get the unmarshalled form (the `@XmlRootElement` annotated class or a `JAXBElement<Foo>`), if the element is not known to the context you'll get an `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

[Full details in Blaise's blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html).

For nodes that get *removed* you should be fine as long as you use types that can be null (`Integer` rather than `int`, `Boolean` rather than `boolean`, etc).

Comment: Thanks,, It works fine. Only problem I am facing now is my xml have many objects (child xml), so I have to apply @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) in each child xml. Is there any way, if I add @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) in parent xml and it works for all child xmls?

Answer (score 22):

Use `JAXB.unmarshal()` to simply create Java objects from XML.

By default it is very liberal.

Quoting from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html):

> In addition, the unmarshal methods have the following characteristic:
>
> 1. Schema validation is not performed on the input XML. The processing will try to continue even if there are errors in the XML, as much as possible. Only as the last resort, this method fails with DataBindingException.

So what `JAXB.unmarshal()` does is it tries to "transfer" as much data from XML to Java as possible, and it doesn't care if there is no Java field for an XML element or attribute, and it also doesn't care if there is a Java field for which there is no XML element or attribute.

### Example

Let's try to unmarshal the following XML to an instance of `java.awt.Point`:

```
<p hi="Yo">
    <y>123</y>
    <peach>weor</peach>
</p>
```

The Java code:

```
String s = "<p hi=\"Yo\"><y>123</y><peach>weor</peach></p>";
Point p = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(s), Point.class);
System.out.println(p); // Prints "java.awt.Point[x=0,y=123]"
```

We told `JAXB.unmarshal()` to parse a `java.awt.Point` instance. The input XML contains an element `<y>` which can be matched with `Point.y` so an `int` was parsed and set to `Point.y`. No XML data was found for `Point.x` so it was not touched. There were no match for the attribute `hi` and the XML element `<peach>`, so they were simply not used for anything.

We got absolutely no `Exception` here, and the most that was possible was parsed and transferred from XML to Java.

Comment: Just like in rpg, the most powerful tool an actor could use to survive is often given as an born gift.