# Java feed XML with namespace bind using JAXB

Tags: java, spring, xml-parsing, jaxb, resttemplate

I am trying to bind email element in below sample xml file but cant not bind it properly.  I am getting null.

Sample XML

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:api="http://www.example.com/publications/api">
<api:schema-version>5.3</api:schema-version>
<category scheme="http://www.example.com/publications/atom/feeds/" term="item" label="Item" />
<id>tag:elements@abcd,5.15:/proted-api/v5.5/feeds/users/12312</id>
  <entry>
   <id>tag:elements@abcd,5.15:/proted-api/v5.5/users/12312</id>
   <category scheme="http://www.example.com/publications/atom/entries/" term="item" label="Item" />
   <content type="xhtml">
   <api:object category="user" id="12312" proprietary-id="abcd123">
      <api:last-name>Jo</api:last-name>
      <api:first-name>Deo</api:first-name>
      <api:email-address>jode@example.com</api:email-address>
    </api:object>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Feed.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Feed {

@XmlElement(name="entry")
private Entry entry;

public Entry getEntry() {
    return entry;
}

public void setEntry(Entry entry) {
    this.entry = entry;
}
}
```

Entry.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {

@XmlElement(name="object", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
private Object object;

public Object getObject() {
    return object;
}

public void setObject(Object object) {
    this.object = object;
}
}
```

Object.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Object {

@XmlElement(name="email-address",namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
private String email;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

Test code

```
//code here to read
Feed feed = response.getBody();
System.out.println("object email = " +feed.getEntry().getObject().getEmail());
```

Full XML file

```
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:api="http://www.example.com/publications/api">
    <api:schema-version>5.5</api:schema-version>
    <category scheme="http://www.example.com/publications/atom/feeds/" term="item" label="Item" />
    <id>tag:elements@Test,5.15:/secure-api/v5.5/feeds/users/676</id>
    <updated>2019-06-17T09:04:39.87+01:00</updated>
    <generator uri="https://test.com/" version="5.15">Example Elements</generator>
    <icon>https://test.com:8091/secure-api/v5.5/Example.ico</icon>
    <rights>This data is the property of the Organisation, and can only be used with permission.</rights>
    <subtitle>This feed represents a single user.</subtitle>
    <link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" href="https://test.com:8091/secure-api/v5.5/users/676" />
    <title>John deo</title>
    <author>
    <name>Example Elements at Test PROD</name>
    </author>
    <entry>
    <id>tag:elements@Test,5.15:/secure-api/v5.5/users/676</id>
    <category scheme="http://www.example.com/publications/atom/entries/" term="item" label="Item" />
    <updated>2019-06-17T09:04:39.87+01:00</updated>
    <link type="application/atom+xml" rel="alternate" href="https://test.com:8091/secure-api/v5.5/users/676" />
    <title>John deo</title>
    <content type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <p>User</p>
    <a href="https://test.com:8091/secure-api/v5.5/users/676/photo?type=profile">Photo</a>
    <p>
    <a href="https://test.com:8091/secure-api/v5.5/users/676/relationships">Relationships</a>
    with other data
    </p>
    </div>
    </content>
    <api:object category="user" id="676" proprietary-id="abcd1247" username="abcd1247" last-affected-when="2019-06-17T09:04:39.87+01:00" last-modified-when="2018-11-29T10:28:43.403+00:00" href="https://test.com:8091/secure-api/v5.5/users/676" created-when="2010-05-04T09:49:46.507+01:00" type-id="1" type="person">
    <!-- User type 1 is "person" -->
    <api:ever-approved>true</api:ever-approved>
    <api:is-public>false</api:is-public>
    <api:is-login-allowed>true</api:is-login-allowed>
    <api:title>Prof</api:title>
    <api:initials>Jo</api:initials>
    <api:last-name>John</api:last-name>
    <api:first-name>Deo</api:first-name>
    <api:email-address>John.deo@example.com</api:email-address>
    <api:known-as>Liz</api:known-as>
    <api:primary-group-descriptor>ABCS</api:primary-group-descriptor>
    <api:arrive-date>2009-10-05</api:arrive-date>
    <api:user-search-settings>
    <api:default>
    </api:default>
    </api:user-search-settings>
    <api:records>
    <api:record format="native" id="3245433412" source-id="1" source-name="manual" source-display-name="Manual">
    <api:native />
    </api:record>
    </api:records>
    <api:fields />
    <api:relationships href="https://test.com:8091/secure-api/v5.5/users/676/relationships" />
    <api:user-identifier-associations user-id="676" proprietary-id="abcd1247" username="abcd1247">
    </api:user-identifier-associations>
    </api:object>
    </entry>
    </feed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your POJOs structure does not match the xml (and as we found out in the end, RestTemplate was not making use of JAXB annotations see Edit 4 below).

Let's fix that so you are able to unmarshall properly.

Most of the fields are using the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace. We'll use package-info instead of adding it in each element. So create a file package-info.java in the package of your classes with contents:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package the.package.of.your.classes;
```

Then let's fix feed. Your xml has elements that your class did not, and this is a problem because it encounters unexpected elements. Feed would be:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Feed {

    @XmlElement(name="schema-version", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private String schemaVersion;
    @XmlElement
    private String category;
    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name="entry")
    private Entry entry;

}
```

Note that schema-version has different namespace than what we have in package-info so we explicitly override it in the annotations.

Now, this is simplified. For example category has xml attributes for example term and label. If you want to get this info, you should create a class to represent Category instead of a String. But if you do not, the Feed like this, allows us to continue with unmarshalling. Next is Entry:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {


    @XmlElement
    private String id;
    @XmlElement
    private String category;
    @XmlElement
    private String content;

    @XmlElement(name="object", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private ApiObject object;

}
```

Again attributes are ignored here with use of String. I changed Object to a class called ApiObject which has the structure that matches the xml. It looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ApiObject {

    @XmlElement(name= "last-name", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement(name = "first-name", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement(name = "email-address", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

And last thing, the xml. It is not valid xml, tag "content" is not closed in the pasted sample. I changed it to `<content type="xhtml" />` to test my solution.

And indeed it works and unmarshalls fine :)

EDIT to respond:

For question 1, you would add the namespace in each element that doesnt specify directly a namespace now.

For question 2, You can ignore unknown elements using what was proposed here: [JAXB Ignore 'extra' elements from Response XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621655/jaxb-ignore-extra-elements-from-response-xml)

Feed for example would look like:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Feed {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<Object> anything;

    @XmlElement(name="entry", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    private Entry entry;


}
```

EDIT 2:

Take the xml you try to unmarshall and do something like below:

```
try {
            File file = new File("/path/to/your/file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(YouRootClass.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(
                    new ValidationEventHandler() {
                        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event ) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(event.getMessage(),
                                    event.getLinkedException());
                        }
                    });
            YouRootClass pojo = (YouRootClass) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Whatever mismatch there is between your xml and POJOs will be thrown as an exception and you can work your way to correct it

EDIT 3:

Feed

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Feed {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<Object> anything;

    @XmlElement(name="entry", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    private Entry entry;

}
```

Entry

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {


    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<Object> anything;

    @XmlElement(name="object", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private ApiObject object;

}
```

ApiObject:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ApiObject {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<Object> anything;

    @XmlElement(name= "last-name", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement(name = "first-name", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement(name = "email-address", namespace = "http://www.example.com/publications/api")
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

EDIT 4:

In your github project, class Test after creating RestTemplate (line 31) add:

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
messageConverters.add(jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter);
rest.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

Comment: Thank you mart, 2 things to ask. 1st how i change code without using package file. 2nd, in Feed class schemaVersion,category,id do i have to include? File i have provided is minified version of actual file .. i have around 50 elements, so do i have to add all 50 elements to Feed class?

Comment: @VK321 I am not in my machine now. Later will paste how I   unmarshall the xml so you can try. can you also put on your question how you unmarshall? did you fix the issue in the xml? paste the complete xml maybe so I can try on the same input you have?

Comment: @VK321 I ll put in the answer a way to run your unmarshalling with your xml and see what causes the problem.

Comment: Mart, thank you v much for spending time. I tested i do not get any error now but still null value. what if i upload complete file, will you able to help me then?

Comment: @VK321 yes please do

Comment: just to add, with my current code if i do feed.getEntry().getObject().getId() it prints id which is propery but nulls for elements

Comment: @VK321 it is strange that you did not get exceptions with the code I pasted to run. I will make another edit with all your classes to properly unmarshall. Ignoring fields you do not care and using those you seem to need in the question. If it still does not work, I will make a small github project and you can clone and try from there. First tho please try what is in edit 3

Comment: @VK321 ok updated answer. Give it a go and let me know :)

Comment: @VK321 that is very strange. Ok check this repo, the answer to your question is here: https://github.com/martidis/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/jaxb/src/main/java/com/tasosmartidis/stackoverflow/jaxb/ignorefields/q56752517. Check the unit test here for the unmarshalling https://github.com/martidis/stackoverflow-answers/blob/master/jaxb/src/test/java/com/tasosmartidis/stackoverflow/jaxb/ignorefields/q56752517/FeedTest.java. Tell me if this works

Comment: @VK321 alright I see the problem. Your RestTemplate does not know about jaxb annotations. Give you last edit what to add in the test you created. Check in answer edit 4

Comment: mart, thank you v much helping me. It did work!!!! Thanks a million. I have another question related to this if you could help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777286/