# Java spring XML binding based on conditions using JAXB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am binding XML to object using JAXB, is it possible to bind based on conditions such as

Bind `href` attribute in `api:page` element where attribute `position` is equal to `next`.

Or get all records as standard list and then filter out by using  `if condition`

```
<api:pagination results-count="93" items-per-page="25">
  <api:page position="this" href="https://url1.com" />
  <api:page position="next" href="https://url1.com?pid=2" />
</api:pagination>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to make a transformation for such a simple setup.Take advantage of @XmlAnyElement https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html and just map your collection as a list of Elements.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "pagination")
@XmlAnyElement
public List<Element> getPages() {
        return pages;
 }
```

Where Element is `org.w3c.dom.Element`

The `@XmlElementWrapper` is optional, if you want you can map your pagination element. I am not sure you need it though.

Then you extract the position with:

```
page.getAttribute("position")
```

and

```
page.getAttribute("href")
```

for the url

Comment: what is Element class here?

Comment: @VK321 org.w3c.dom.Element